# Negation of a statement?

Tags: quantifiers

L = {M, w| M is a TM, w is a string, and for some nonempty strings x, y,
w = xy, M accepts xyx and M rejects yxy}..

Im having issues representing this in mathematical form.

For example what would the negation of "M accepts xyx" be?
or 
"for some nonempty strings x, y,
w = xy,"

How would I negate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "representing this in mathematical form," but I'll try to help with quantifiers.

To answer your two questions:

#### Negating "$M$ accepts $xyx$"

There are three possibilities for a Turing Machine on any input: accept, reject, or "run forever" (not halt). So, the negation of "$M \text{ accepts } xyx$" corresponds to "$M$ rejects $xyx$ or $M$ does not halt on $xyx$."

#### Negating "for some non-empty strings $x$, $y$, $w = xy$"

By "for some," are you saying "for all" or "there exist"?

It sounds like "for some non-empty strings $x$, $y$, $w = xy$" is actually "for $\textit{all}$ non-empty strings $x$, $y$, where $w = xy$". In general, the negation of a statement of the form

$$\text{for all } x_1, x_2, ... , x_n, S$$

(where $S$ is some statement) is the statement

$$\text{there exist } x_1, x_2, ... , x_n | \neg S$$

Where "|" indicates "such that." The reasoning behind this is that the opposite of "this rule always applies" is "there exists a counterexample to this rule."

So in your case, you would be negating "for all non-empty strings $x$, $y$, where $w = xy$, $M$ accepts $xyx$ and $M$ rejects $yxy$." By the rule above, our negation is "there exist non-empty strings $x$, $y$, where $w = xy$, such that $M$ does not accept $xyx$ or $M$ does not reject $yxy$."

Note that the meanings of "$M$ does not accept $xyx$" and "$M$ does not reject $yxy$" have been explained above, and that "$M$ does not accept $xyx$ or $M$ does not reject $yxy$" is the result of De Morgan's law.

Comment: I was told:The negation of "M accepts xyx" is not "M rejects xyx". Thats what confuses me

Comment: Indeed, since $M$ doesn't have to reject $xyx$ to not accept $xyx$: $M$ could also not halt on $xyx$. Do you mean you were told that the negation of "$M$ accepts $xyx$" is "$\neg (M$ rejects $xyx)$? If so, I would say this is wrong, unless there is some hidden assumption that $M$ always halts.

Comment: Reject is not the same as negation of accept, M could've not accepted and not rejected at the same time. The correct negation would be M failed to accept. @user126885

Comment: No I wasnt told what the negation of M accepts xyx was.  when I suggested that perhaps reject could be the negation, I was told that it was incorrect.

Comment: I see. In that case, Ahmed's comment should clear things up.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla so the correct negation for accepts would does not accept(Which means 1 of 2 things can occur? It loops or it rejects) correct? In that case for both statements I would say M failed to accept or M failed to reject. Which in turn implies that all three cases could occur

Comment: In answer to your first question: yes, it loops or rejects. As for your second question: not quite, since the full statement is "$M$ accepts $xyx$ and $M$ rejects $yxy$," and it is not guaranteed that $xyx = yxy$. So, you should say "$M$ fails to accept $xyx$ or $M$ fails to reject $yxy$."

Comment: Sorry for being a bit unclear, M  fails to accept xyx or MM fails to reject yxy is similar to saying(M loops on or rejects xyx OR M loops on or accepts yxy) Correct? So @BrianYao that would mean that this question would not be recognizable, because how could the machine potentially accept or loop on the same xyx

Comment: For your first question: yes, that is correct. For your second question: not necessarily. When we say that $M$ accepts $xyx$ OR $M$ does not halt on $xyx$, we do not mean to say that both necessarily occur (that would be an AND statement, not an OR statement like we have here). The OR statement just claims that _at least one_ of those two possibilities will occur.